# Application of Picard's existence uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I have done the 1st part, i am struggling with the 2nd part of this problem. If $y_0 > 0$, then I calculated $y(t)$ using separation of variables method and I got $y(t) = \frac14(t+c)^2$, now $y(t) = 0$ for $t$ belonging to $[0,c]$ and $y(t) = \frac14(t-c)^2$ for $t\ge 0$.

After that how do I proceed? Do I need to show that its Lipschitz for $t>0$?

Kindly help me with the next few parts as I am not able to follow those. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you need to convince yourself which branch to take, $y(t)=(t+c)^2/4$ or $y(t)=(t-c)^2/4$. By the Picard theorem you know that there can be just one! Then you can compute $c$ in terms of $y_0$. Then for the values of $t$, you need to know when the Picard theorem breaks down. This is exactly in the point where $\sqrt{y}$ stops being continuously differentiable. For which values of $t$ does this hold?

Comment: I calculated that, I got 1/4*(t+2sqrt(y_o))^2 after putting y(0)=y_o in the solution equation of y(t), I think the solution is going to be valid for all values of t from [-infinity, 0) and (0, infinity] except t = -2.(sqrt(y_o)), b/c at that point the entire solution will become invalid. Also, we cant extend the solution, right?? Please help me on the last part of this question, i.e. for which values of t you get uniqueness using Picard's theorem.